# Laravel Sail - No response in browser

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

When running

`sudo APP_PORT=3001 ./vendor/bin/sail up`

In the terminal I am expecting to see the default laravel splash screen on `http://localhost:3001`. But instead I see an error message `This page isn’t workinglocalhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

I'm running laravel 8 with sail on windows 10 using WSL(ubuntu).

I can see both the DB and app containers are running fine from within docker desktop(both green)

Does anyone know the fix for this?

docker-compose.yml

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:8000'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
    mariadb:
        image: 'mariadb:10'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmariadb:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmariadb:
        driver: local
```

Comment: Did you try localhost:8000?

Comment: @tirtakeniten yes. Same error

Comment: Are you sure the APP_PORT is translated? Maybe try "3001" hardcoded in the docker-compose file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @BertC said I changed the ports line in docker-compose.yml to be - "9192:80" and ran `sail up` again and it worked. Thank you @BertC

Comment: The suggestion from BertC doesn't seem to be showing and it isn't clear where you added 9191:80 and why, so this is answer really doesn't help.